# No result returned from the nest c# elasticsearch query

Tags: c#-4.0, elasticsearch, nest

I am indexing an attachment field. The POST query in sense returns expected resultset. 
My query is

```
POST /mydocs/_search
{
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
        "must" : [
            { "match" : { "file.content":"abc"} },
            { "match":{"otherDetails":"asd"}},
            { "match" : { "filePermissionInfo.accountValue" : "xyz"} }
        ]
    }
  }
 }
```

I need to convert it to a c# Nest code. I tried converting it, but its not returning any result,even it contains data. If I remove the

```
m.Match(mt1 => mt1.Field(f1 => f1.File.Coontent).Query(queryTerm))
```

from the below experssion, it returns a result set. Is there any problem with the attachement field?

```
 client.Search<IndexDocument>(s => s
                            .Index("mydocs")
                            .Query(q => q
                            .Bool(b => b
                            .Must(m =>
                            m.Match(mt1 => mt1.Field(f1 => f1.File.Coontent).Query(queryTerm)) &&
                            m.Match(mt2 => mt2.Field(f2 => f2.FilePermissionInfo.First().SecurityIdValue).Query(accountName)) &&
                                 m.Match(mt3 => mt3.Field(f3 => f3.OtherDetails).Query(other)) 
                             )))
                             );
```

My mapping is

```
{
 "mydocs": {
  "mappings": {
     "indexdocument": {
        "properties": {
           "docLocation": {
              "type": "string",
              "index": "not_analyzed",
              "store": true
           },
           "documentType": {
              "type": "string",
              "store": true
           },
           "file": {
              "type": "attachment",
              "fields": {
                 "content": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                    "analyzer": "full"
                 },
                 "author": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "title": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                    "analyzer": "full"
                 },
                 "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "date": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                 },
                 "keywords": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "content_type": {
                    "type": "string"
                 },
                 "content_length": {
                    "type": "integer"
                 },
                 "language": {
                    "type": "string"
                 }
              }
           },
           "filePermissionInfo": {
              "properties": {
                 "fileSystemRights": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true
                 },
                 "securityIdValue": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true
                 }
              }
           },
           "id": {
              "type": "double",
              "store": true
           },
           "lastModifiedDate": {
              "type": "date",
              "store": true,
              "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
           },
           "otherDetails": {
              "type": "string"
           },
           "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "store": true,
              "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets"
           }
        }
     }
  }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the query hasn't been translated to NEST correctly. In the query you have

```
"filePermissionInfo.accountValue"
```

but in the NEST query, you only have

```
f2 => f2.FilePermissionInfo
```

which would result only in `filePermissionInfo`. You need to change this to

```
f2 => f2.FilePermissionInfo.AccountValue
```

Comment: I updated the query, but still no result returned. Can you please help me to transfer the query to Nest correctly

Comment: @AjA - but I don't know what your data is and what you're trying to do :) I would at breaking down the individual query components piece by piece to understand how each is contributing to the final result. If you have a specific document that you think should match for a particular query, you can use the `_explain` API to understand why it does or doesn't match - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html